I have created a custom S3-Sink-Connector which reads Avro messages, validates with the schema and dumps into S3 Bucket in the parquet format
This is my S3SinkTask code where I'm facing these errors, please help me resolve the errors
C:\\Users\\ADMIN\\Downloads\\Projects\\custom-s3-sink-connector\>curl -X GET http://localhost:8083/connectors/s3-sink-connector/status

{"name":"s3-sink-connector","connector":{"state":"RUNNING","worker_id":"connect:8083"},"tasks":\[{"id":0,"state":"FAILED","worker_id":"connect:8083","trace":"org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Exiting WorkerSinkTask due to unrecoverable exception.\\n\\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:618)\\n\\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:336)\\n\\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:237)\\n\\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:206)\\n\\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:202)\\n\\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:257)\\n\\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.Plugins.lambda$withClassLoader$1(Plugins.java:181)\\n\\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)\\n\\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)\\n\\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)\\n\\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)\\n\\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)\\nCaused by: java.lang.NullPointerException\\n\\tat com.example.S3SinkTask.shouldFlush(S3SinkTask.java:105)\\n\\tat com.example.S3SinkTask.put(S3SinkTask.java:81)\\n\\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:587)\\n\\t... 11 more\\n"}\],"type":"sink"}

These are the errors that I'm facing
package com.example;

import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSStaticCredentialsProvider;
import com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.regions.Regions;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3ClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.PutObjectRequest;
import org.apache.avro.Schema;
import org.apache.avro.file.DataFileWriter;
import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter;
import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericRecord;
import org.apache.avro.io.DatumReader;
import org.apache.avro.io.DecoderFactory;
import org.apache.avro.io.DatumWriter;
import org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificDatumReader;
import org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Struct;
import org.apache.kafka.connect.sink.SinkRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.connect.sink.SinkTask;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient;
import io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.SchemaRegistryClient;
import io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.SchemaMetadata;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.*;

public class S3SinkTask extends SinkTask {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(S3SinkTask.class);

    private AmazonS3 s3Client;
    private String bucketName;
    private Map<String, List<GenericRecord>> topicBuffers;
    private int batchSize;
    private String schemaRegistryUrl;
    private SchemaRegistryClient schemaRegistryClient;
    private final Map<String, Schema> schemaCache = new HashMap<>();

    @Override
    public void start(Map<String, String> props) {
        String accessKeyId = props.get(S3SinkConfig.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID);
        String secretAccessKey = props.get(S3SinkConfig.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY);
        bucketName = props.get(S3SinkConfig.S3_BUCKET_NAME);
        schemaRegistryUrl = props.get(S3SinkConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL);

        BasicAWSCredentials awsCreds = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKeyId, secretAccessKey);
        s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                .withRegion(Regions.fromName(props.get(S3SinkConfig.S3_REGION)))
                .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCreds))
                .build();

        topicBuffers = new HashMap<>();

        batchSize = Integer.parseInt(props.get(S3SinkConfig.S3_BATCH_SIZE));

        schemaRegistryClient = new CachedSchemaRegistryClient(schemaRegistryUrl, 100);
    }

    @Override
    public void put(Collection<SinkRecord> records) {
        for (SinkRecord record : records) {
            String topic = record.topic();
            try {
                Schema schema = getSchemaForTopic(topic);
                GenericRecord avroRecord = convertToAvroRecord(record.value(), schema);
                topicBuffers.computeIfAbsent(topic, k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(avroRecord);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error("Failed to process record: {}", record, e);
            }

            if (shouldFlush(topic)) {
                flushRecords(topic);
            }
        }
    }

    private Schema getSchemaForTopic(String topic) throws Exception {
        if (schemaCache.containsKey(topic)) {
            return schemaCache.get(topic);
        }
        String subject = topic + "-value";
        SchemaMetadata schemaMetadata = schemaRegistryClient.getLatestSchemaMetadata(subject);
        Schema schema = new Schema.Parser().parse(schemaMetadata.getSchema());
        schemaCache.put(topic, schema);
        return schema;
    }

    private GenericRecord convertToAvroRecord(Object value, Schema schema) throws Exception {
        if (value instanceof Struct) {
            Struct struct = (Struct) value;
            org.apache.avro.generic.GenericRecordBuilder recordBuilder = new org.apache.avro.generic.GenericRecordBuilder(schema);

            for (Schema.Field field : schema.getFields()) {
                Object fieldValue = struct.get(field.name());
                recordBuilder.set(field, fieldValue);
            }

            return recordBuilder.build();
        } else if (value instanceof byte[]) {
            byte[] payload = (byte[]) value;
            DatumReader<GenericRecord> reader = new SpecificDatumReader<>(schema);
            return reader.read(null, DecoderFactory.get().binaryDecoder(payload, null));
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported value type: " + value.getClass().getName());
        }
    }

    private boolean shouldFlush(String topic) {
        List<GenericRecord> buffer = topicBuffers.get(topic);
        if (buffer == null) {
            return false;
        }
        return buffer.size() >= batchSize;
    }

    private void flushRecords(String topic) {
        if (topicBuffers.containsKey(topic) && !topicBuffers.get(topic).isEmpty()) {
            try {
                File tempFile = File.createTempFile("kafka-avro-", ".avro");
                tempFile.deleteOnExit();

                DatumWriter<GenericRecord> datumWriter = new GenericDatumWriter<>(getSchemaForTopic(topic));
                DataFileWriter<GenericRecord> dataFileWriter = new DataFileWriter<>(datumWriter);

                dataFileWriter.create(getSchemaForTopic(topic), tempFile);

                for (GenericRecord record : topicBuffers.get(topic)) {
                    dataFileWriter.append(record);
                }

                dataFileWriter.close();

                String key = String.format("%s/%s", topic, generateFileKey());
                s3Client.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, key, tempFile));
                topicBuffers.get(topic).clear();

                tempFile.delete();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error("Failed to flush records for topic: {}", topic, e);
            }
        }
    }

    private String generateFileKey() {
        String timestamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss").format(new Date());
        return String.format("event-%s.avro", timestamp);
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        for (String topic : topicBuffers.keySet()) {
            flushRecords(topic);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String version() {
        return "1.0";
    }
}

